# Class Errors with remote PHP website being setup locally with MAMP

Tags: php, mysql, mamp

I've worked to narrow down the list of possible problems with a remote website I've been asked to duplicate locally.

- I've updated the relative/absolute paths across the entire website.
- I've downgraded MAMP to an earlier version of PHP.
- I've confirmed file permissions are the same on local as remote.

I'm confused as to why if the exact structure of the website is duplicated locally, why the code would have a Fatal error. How can I debug further or improve my "download" of the website to the local MAMP directory?

`Notice: Undefined index: errors in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/core/config/config.php on line 21
2 Warning require_once(index.php) [function.require-once]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/core/config/config.php 116`

`Fatal error: require_once() [function.require]: Failed opening required 'index.php' (include_path='/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/core/classes/:/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/view/classes/:/:/:/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/core/pear/') in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/core/config/config.php on line 116`

This is the autoload function that causes the problem - I just can't figure out why:

```
`//AUTOLOAD
function __autoload($class_name)
{
    if($GLOBALS['show_dev'])
    {
        if(!isset($GLOBALS['starttime'])) {
            $GLOBALS['starttime'] = microtime(true);
        }
        $stack = array();
        foreach(debug_backtrace() as $stack_item) {
            $stack[] = $stack_item['file'] . ': ' . $stack_item['function'] . ': ' .                        $stack_item['line'];
        }
        $debug =  array(
            'Loading Class' => $class_name,
            'Class Loaded at' => number_format(microtime(true) - $GLOBALS['starttime'], 4, '.', ''), 
            'Memory (MB) used before class load' => (memory_get_usage() / (1024 * 1024)),
            'Current Stack Trace'=> implode("<br />", $stack)
        );

        $GLOBALS['debug'][] = $debug;
    }
    echo $class_name;
    require_once($class_name . ".php");
}`
```

After reviewing the setup of the constant variable definitions, I noticed the "realpath" function is used - why is realpath needed in this scenario?

`    function setConstants()
    {

```
    if (!$this->info['constants'] || $GLOBALS['nocache'])
    {
        $this->info['constants'] = array
        (
            'SECTION'       => $this->section,
            'CONST_DEFINED' => true,
            'PEAR_ROOT'     => "/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/core/pear/",
            'SERVERS'       => "localhost:8888",

            'DOCUMENT_ROOT' => realpath('/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/view/') . "/",           
            'CORE_ROOT'     => realpath('/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/core/') . "/",           
            'CLASS_PATH'    => realpath('/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/classes/') . "/",            
            'CORE_CLASS_PATH'   => realpath('/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/core/classes/') . "/",

            'EMAIL_DATA_PATH'   => realpath('/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/core/emails/data/') . "/",

            'CORE_DATA_PATH'    => realpath('/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/view/'.$this->section.'/data/') . "/",
            'CORE_ACTION_PATH'  => realpath('/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/view/'.$this->section.'/actions/') . "/",
            'CORE_CONTROL_PATH' => realpath('/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/view/'.$this->section.'/controllers/') . "/",
            'CORE_HTML_PATH' => realpath('/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/view/'.$this->section.'/html/') . "/",

            'COMPONENT_DATA_PATH'   => realpath('/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/view/'.$this->section.'/data/components/') . "/",
            'COMPONENT_HTML_PATH' => realpath('/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/view/'.$this->section.'/html/components/') . "/",              
        );

        //$GLOBALS['cache']->set($this->cache_file_name,$GLOBALS['info'],1);
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you sure that include_path is the same on both servers? I don't see a `.` mentioned in there, which means the current directory is NOT going to be used.

Comment: Do you have read permissions on the file for Apache?

Comment: @eomer - Yes - read and write permissions.

Comment: @MarcB The include path is the same on both servers - it's the same, less the change I made to the initial path.

Answer (score 0):

Read this SO post. [PHP Zend require_once](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11188603/php-zend-require-once-failed-to-open-stream-and-failed-opening-required). From what you posted, it seems you don't have a realpath set. If so, this would cause the failure.